# Deleted "Real Name" returns after logging in on mobile site

Tags: bug, profile-page, mobile-web, stack-exchange-openid, real-name

In my profile, I had once entered a real name and after some time I decided to delete it. On my PC in my profile I clicked edit and deleted the name and it stopped showing up.

However, every now and again I noticed that it was visible again, although I didn't change my profile. I found out that this always happens when I log in from the mobile site.

The name will show up in my profile, but when I'm on the editing page the real name field is still empty and I just have to click "save profile" to delete the name again.

I did some testing and found that this happens on all Stackexchange sites, but only on those where I specifically log in **using the login page** in the mobile version by entering email and password. It doesn't happen on sites where I get logged in automatically because I'm already logged in on another Stackexchange site.

I'd like to keep the name deleted, but every time I use the mobile site it returns.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The Real Name is private - only you, Stack Exchange staff and moderators can see it.

Comment: @Oded I didn't know that. The problem is the same anyway, I'd like to delete it.

Comment: What OpenID provider are you using?

Comment: What do you mean? You clear "Real Name", click save, go to mobile version and see your real name again?

Comment: @nicael I clear Real Name on PC, click save, the name is deleted. I log in on mobile, the name is there again on the mobile profile and on the PC profile. The field in the editing window is still empty, but the name is in the profile again.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I don't know what you mean, sorry. What's an OpenID provider? :/

Comment: Just caching?.. Try clearing you cache...

Comment: @Kodama when you log in you can choose between Google, Facebook, Stack Exchange, or "more login options". Which of those you choose when you are logging in? (each of those is known as OpenID provider)

Comment: @ShadowWizard StackExchange

Comment: @Oded any chance the Stack Exchange OpenID cache the real name somewhere, server side?

Comment: @nicael I cleared the cache on both mobile and PC before testing it. The name reappears anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Stack Exchange OpenID service *does* have a Real Name field on the account profile. This does not get cleared by deleting it from your network account profiles. The only way to clear it is to actually [login to the OpenID itself](https://openid.stackexchange.com) and edit your profile:

> [image: OpenID Edit Profile]

So long as your real name is still listed there, it will automatically populate into your profile whenever you use the Stack Exchange OpenID to login to your account.